# Evaluation control in function definition: Total interferes with Evaluate

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, hold

Here is a simple example to illustrate my problem:

```
expr = {a + b*Exp[-r t], a - b*Exp[-r t]}
(* {a + b E^(-r t), a - b E^(-r t)} *)

g[t_, b_] := Total[Evaluate[expr], {2}]

g[10, {b1, b2}]
(* {a + b E^(-r t), a - b E^(-r t)} *)
```

It looks is like `Total[]` undoes the `Evaluate[]` statement. Indeed:

```
g[10, 1]
(* {a + b E^(-r t), a - b E^(-r t)} *)
```

What I wanted and expected was the same output as when doing

```
h[t_, b_] := Evaluate[expr]
    
Total[h[10, {b1, b2}], {2}]  
(* {2 a + b1 E^(-10 r) + b2 E^(-10 r), 
     2 a - b1 E^(-10 r) - b2 E^(-10 r)} *)
```

I would like to understand why it can't be done the way I did, and how to do it instead (in the function definition). I am using Mathematica 13.3 on Windows.

Comment: To make your test cases a bit simpler, look at : `expr = x; f1[x_] := expr; f2[x_] := Evaluate[expr]; f3[x_] := f4[Evaluate[expr]];
{f1[0], f2[0], f3[0]}`

Comment: Right. I get {x, 0, f4[x]}, and it is the last output I don't understand.

Comment: Actually, it is the _second_ output that should pop-out to you :) You may want to look at `Definition[f1]`, `Definition[f2]` and `Definition[f3]`. You will see that in `f2`, `expr` evaluated to `x` already at the time you defined the function, while in the other two cases, `expr` remained intact, as expected. `x` in `expr` will then not be automatically replaced with the function argument `x`! There are various solutions, for example: `g[t_, bb_] := Total[expr /. b -> bb, {2}]` or `Clear[expr]; expr[b_] := {a + b*Exp[-r t], a - b*Exp[-r t]}; g[t_, b_] := Total[expr[b], {2}]`

Comment: No, that is precisely why first and second do not pop out to me. They gave  what I expected. For example for f2, the defining statement is already equivalent to f2[x_]: = x at the outset, so it is clear that f2[0]=0. I would have thought that in the same way, the definition for f3 is f3[x]:=f4[x], since I asked for the inside of f4 to be evaluated immediately. But as Bob Hanlon says below, it appears Evaluate is buried too deeply - which IMO somewhat defeats the purpose of it.

Comment: If you read the documentation for `Evaluate`, it states "Evaluate works only on the first level, directly inside a held function". This seems perfectly reasonable to me, because otherwise the evaluation process would need to parse the expression tree entirely looking for any `Evaluate`s before moving on.

Comment: Fair enough. I saw that, but it was not obvious to me that it is not the first level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = {a + b*Exp[-r t], a - b*Exp[-r t]};

g[t_, b_] := Total[Evaluate[expr], {2}]
```

The [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) is buried too deep to be evaluated when `g` is defined

```
?g
```

[image]

Consequently, the `b` and `t` in `expr` are not the same as the localized `b` and `t` in the subsequent evaluation of `g`. You would need

```
g[t2_, b2_] := Total[Evaluate[expr /. {t -> t2, b -> b2}], {2}]

?g
```

[image]

```
g[10, {b1, b2}]

(* {2 a + b1 E^(-10 r) + b2 E^(-10 r), 2 a - b1 E^(-10 r) - b2 E^(-10 r)} *)
```

But then the `Evaluate` is not necessary.

```
Clear[g]

g[t2_, b2_] := Total[expr /. {t -> t2, b -> b2}, {2}]

g[10, {b1, b2}]

(* {2 a + b1 E^(-10 r) + b2 E^(-10 r), 2 a - b1 E^(-10 r) - b2 E^(-10 r)} *)
```